# Calculate Norm Operator

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to solve this exercice:

> Let $\omega(y)=y^{-4}$ and $L^{1}(\mathbb{R},\omega)$ the space of measurable functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that $g\omega$ is Lebesgue integrable and the norm is defined as $||g||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R},\omega)}=\int_\mathbb{R}|g(y)|\omega(y)dy$ 
>   Calculate the norm of the operator: $$Tg(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-xy^{4}}g(y)dy$$

Now, this is the first time I've encountered norms with integral signs and L-spaces with an "associated" function, so it's blurring my thinking...
There are some things I don't understand:
1/ Is: $||Tg||=\int_\mathbb{R}|(\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-yy^{4}}g(y)dy)|y^{-4}dy$ ? I don't think so because I'd have two integrals for y...
2/ Is it then: $||Tg||=\int_\mathbb{R}|e^{-xy^{4}}g(y)|y^{-4}dy$ ? Then $|||T|||\leq 1$ ,right?

These questions on the steps I'm following aside, my goal is to get it done so any other approach is more than welcome if clear enough.

Note: This is from an introduction exercice to Fourier series so if your answer uses any of that, please make small steps in your reasoning.

Comment: The expression 1/ is closer; just do the outer integration with respect to some other variable (maybe $x$, since that's the letter used for $Tg$.)

Comment: But then how will I end up with something times $||g||$ if g is a function of y and $\omega$ is a function of x?

Comment: I don't understand the objection. After the double integral you have a number; compare this to the number $||g||$. This is usually pretty hard, if that is what you were asking.